# Retrofit 2 throwing error Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android, retrofit

Hi I am new to the Retrofit 2.0 library, I am having problems parsing some json. I have looked at some other solutions on Stackoverflow but not having much luck with my problem. I am trying to call an api from android with retrofit 2.0.But it is throwing error Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT.

My response from web api is:

```
{
    "items": [{
        "id": 19,
        "lat": 23.79418,
        "lng": 90.401859,
        "user_id": 1,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "user": {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Tarif",
            "email": "fmt@itc.com",
            "created_at": null,
            "updated_at": null
        }

    }]
}
```

This is how my Model class is:

```
    public class UserResponse {
    private List<Items> items;
    public List<Items> getItems() {
        return items;
    }
    private class Items{
        private String id;
        private String lat;
        private String lng;
        private String user_id;
        private String created_at;
        private String updated_at;
        private List<User> user;

        private class User{
            private String id;
            private String name;
            private String email;
            private String created_at;
            private String updated_at;

            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }

            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }

            public String getEmail() {
                return email;
            }

            public String getCreated_at() {
                return created_at;
            }
            public String getUpdated_at() {
                return updated_at;
            }


        }
        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public String getLat() {
            return lat;
        }
        public String getLng() {
            return lng;
        }
        public String getUser_id() {
            return user_id;
        }
        public String getCreated_at() {
            return created_at;
        }
        public String getUpdated_at() {
            return updated_at;
        }
        public List<User> getUser() {
            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my interface:

```
@GET("coordinates")
 Call <UserResponse> getUsers();
```

This is how I am calling:

```
ITCService service = ApiUtils.createService(ITCService.class);
        Call<UserResponse> call= service.getUsers();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<UserResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<UserResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<UserResponse> response) {

                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    UserResponse res = response.body();
                    Log.e("TAG", res.toString());

                } else {
                    // TODO: toast
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.message(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<UserResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                // TODO: error alert

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`List<User>` should be `HashMap<String,Object>` not a list because it is a `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`.Since you are defining User class in item itself just use `User` instead of List.No need of `HashMap`.

Comment: how can I declare that?

Comment: what will be the key and value?

Comment: just declare User instead of List<User>